# Deployment failed with Netlify on my Angular project with github integration

Tags: angular, github, netlify

I have my Angular project pushed to github and linked that github repo to my netlify account for continous deployment. But when I open the link to my homepage I see a message from netlify that the link is broken.

Link to the github repo: https://github.com/grgkro/SWAB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the overview page of my netlify project I had to go to "Site Settings":

[image: Site Settings]

Here click on "Build & deploy" and enter the build command `npm run build` (npm install is automatically run by netlify). And also change the build directory. Netlify automatically only has dist/ set as dist folder, but Angular projects get build in the folder `build/<project name>`, not `dist/`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should also include `_redirects` file in your src folder to allow routing in you application.
Then, include the file to your assets in `angular.json` as such:

```
"assets": [
              "src/assets",
 ]
```

Inside the file, include this:

```
/*  /index.html 200
```